# Node Version Manager - I have to specify version on each boot?

Tags: linux, node.js, centos7, nvm

On my dev server (CentOS), I installed `nvm` (Node Version Manager) and use that to install various node versions. `nvm` is installed for the root user only.

I noticed that after I restart the server, for `root`, `# node -v` gives me

```
bash: node: command not found
```

Of course I can simply say `# nvm use v0.12.5` but then after another reboot, it doesn't stay. I have to re-specify it again.

Is this normal? Why is this? Is there a way to specify a default so I don't have to do this each time a reboot happens?

Comment: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/698

Comment: Check this tutorial for nvm: http://rainsoft.io/install-node-like-a-boss-with-nvm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an oft-overlooked paragraph at the top of [the **Usage** section of the README](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage) (relevant emphasis mine):

> *You can create an `.nvmrc` file containing version number in the project root directory (or any parent directory).* `nvm use`, `nvm install`, `nvm exec`, `nvm run`, and `nvm which` will all respect an `.nvmrc` file when a version is not supplied.

Using this method, you should be able to create a `.nvmrc` file in the home directory for `root` that would set the desired `node` version on at least interactive shells. Note that attempting to use `nvm` from non-interactive shells would be tricky, as it requires you to source `.nvm/nvm.sh`...

Additionally, you can register an alias named `default` for a specific version with `nvm alias default <version>`.